# New build starts up but no display

Tags: hardware-failure

I've recently assembled the following new build:

8600k i5 1151 intel

1080gtx jet  stream

Z370 AORUS Ultra Gaming

16GB patriot Ram

CX750 corsair PSU

Masterliquid ML240L

The motherboard/fans and gpu come on when power button is pushed - then around 20 seconds later the screen comes on but only displays black then remains that way.

All cables are connected - I've tried the hdmi cable in the gpu and motherboard/ using a dvi cable in both- ram chips in all dual slots and one chip only - battery removed and manual cmos reset - trying different header configurations.

Could it be a bent cpu pin- motherboard grounded on a peg or the cx750 not coping?

Any help is apprecaited at this stage.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you connect the GPU power connection?

Comment: Yes I tried the 4 pin and then the 3 pin after that - then both but still nothing. Also I am using a 150GB SSD and booting from a Windows 10 disc via an optical drive.

Comment: You *must* connect the full-size power connector to the GPU, whichever size it is. It will *not* operate properly without it.

Comment: There's two slots for PCI cables - a 3 pin and a 4 pin. Ive got cables in both and tried just one etc. I've also tried my old 970 in and the computer works. Is this something to do with my bios perhaps?